# I have a problem when open Android studio app

Tags: android, file, events, system

I want to  stop showing file system events processor alot when open Android studio please answer my question
That occur when open Android studio only
What solving

[enter image description here]
I try invalidate cashed and problem not solved
Image show my problem
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnFtr.jpg)

Comment: I think so android studio got currptated, I don't know how. 
But you can reinstall android studio.